# Charge sharing in capacitors with switching pulses

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, passive-networks

I can solve the output voltage for the given circuit below as the clock pulses increase. To find a steady-state value, I found the output voltage till it remained constant (around five clock cycles). But it is so tedious. Is there any intuitive way to find such circuits' steady-state values without tedious calculations?
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Andyaka I got accurate answers, i.e., 0.4 or 0.6. But I am interested in knowing how does the circuit look at steady state to find those values directly.

Answer (score 5):

The exact answer is not possible in a closed form (there are exponential terms in polynomials). But it is possible to approximate it by making a reasonable assumption.

This assumption is that the resistance of the switches (which is not shown) is negligible compared to the impedance of the capacitors. In other words, the switching frequency is slow compared to any of the R_switch*capacitor time constants. With that approximation, charge sharing between capacitors completes in each cycle. This then allows you to replace each capacitor switched between nodes driven with phi1 and phi2 with an equivalent resistance of Req = 1/(C.f).

Thus the circuit simplifies to a R (==1/C.f) between 1V and V0; The output capacitor then becomes a resistor 1/C.f to ground, and the 2C capacitor is 'just' a filter (not replaced with a R).

The ripple is more complex, but starting from the steady state approximations, you can then calculate the perturbations (within each switching cycle) from the two 'C' being connected to the 2C component.

Comment: I appreciate this kind of an answer a lot. It helps build the thought patterns needed in understanding circuits at a more intuitive level. Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

Most questions about steady state have some sort of symmetry to be taken advantage of. That becomes intuitive as you solve more questions. In this question, the symmetry suggests that the voltage of the 2C capacitor will oscillate around 0.5 Volts. This reduces the number of variables and equations in the **system of equations**. You will encounter this term "system of equations" in Matrices topic in math, where to be able to solve for 'n' variables you need 'n' unique equations. I digress...

In the spirit of this question, I think the resistances can be ignored and the questioner wants to know to what values will the capacitors be oscillating between if the charge transfer happens instantaneously and given infinite time to settle.

Kirchhoff's laws are useful in steady states as charge is conserved and in lumped elemental circuits you may use the loop law to derive some equations as well.(This is just a tip and they are generally useful in steady state conditions)

Now lets solve the question at hand, and I will not use the symmetry, rather let it evolve organically out of the equations we will derive. Now let us jump to steady state after the system settles and see what inferences we can draw.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCJrgU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. The 2C capacitor will oscillate between 2 voltage levels. Let us introduce our first 2 variables V2(higher value attained during Phi2 phase) and V1(lower value attained during Phi1 phase).
2. The charge flowing into 2C capacitor during phi2 is the same as the charge flowing out of 2C in phi1 state. Lets call this new variable Q
3. This is the same charge that flows out of C1 when it discharges from 1 volt to steady state voltage V2 during Phi2.
4. This is the same charge that gets transferred to C3 when it charges from 0 volts to steady state value V1 during Phi1.

Now we use our handy capacitor equation

> `Q = CV`
> to derive 3 equation to solve for the three 3 variables.

Eq1 is derived from charge flowing out of C1 during Phi2 when the voltage drops from 1V to V2:

```
Q = C x (1 - V2)      ----(1)
```

Eq2 is derived from charge flowing out of 2C during Phi1 as the voltage drops from V2 to V1:

```
Q = 2C x (V2 - V1)    ----(2)
```

Eq3 is derived from the discharge of C3 during Phi2:

```
Q = C x (V1 - 0)      ----(3)
```

Solve for V1 and V2!
You will get V2 = 0.6V and V1 = 0.4V

Divide Eq1 with Eq3 and you will get

```
1 = (1 - V2)/V1
=> V1 = 1 - V2
=> V2 - 0.5 = 0.5 - V1 (proving our intuition about the voltages oscillating around 0.5V correct.)
```

If we had taken advantage of this symmetry, we would have had to solve 2 equations and 2 variables, the exercise which I will leave to you.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there any intuitive way to find such circuits' steady-state values
> without tedious calculations?*

My intuition tells me to solve using a simulator. It's so easy to solve using a simulator and, you gain insight when studying the waveforms: -

[image]

The first insight is that the voltage at node A0 (my circuit term) is always going to fall to two-thirds of the voltage when S3 is active. There, that's one formula and is easily proven - it'll settle at 0.4 volts. The formula to find the 0.6 volt level is more complex but, I always think that displaying waveforms helps you to deal with that exercise.

The other benefit of using a simulator is that if you need to re-evaluate using different ratios of capacitance then it's literally 30 seconds to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in computing that table you have automatically, it can be done easily.

Consider the charges or voltages of the capacitors (the later is more practical for now) as state variables, and try to come up with a rule for computing the "next state" from the previous one. In this case, you would need two rules to compute: one for the first, and one for the second phase.

Let's label the variables \$v_1\$, \$v_2\$ and \$v_3\$ (and also \$v_2=v_0\$, but I keep the left-to-right ordering for clarity reasons).

In the first step, \$C_1\$ gets connected to the supply, so \$v_1[t+1]=1\$, also \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ get connected together, so their voltage will be \$v_2[t+1]=v_3[t+1]=\frac{2*v_2+v_3}{3}\$. So in the first phase:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1'\\
    v_2'\\
    v_3'\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    \frac{2*v_2+v_3}{3}\\
    \frac{2*v_2+v_3}{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1\\
    v_2\\
    v_3\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At the second phase, \$C_3\$ gets connected to ground, also \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ gets balanced out:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1'\\
    v_2'\\
    v_3'\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{v_1 + 2*v_2}{3}\\
    \frac{v_1 + 2*v_2}{3}\\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\
    \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1\\
    v_2\\
    v_3\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is a simple linear system in discrete time, so the only complication is the two-phase nature of it.

If we introduce a new dummy state variable \$d\$, and always keep it \$1\$, then we can even get rid of the constants.
First phase:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1'\\
    v_2'\\
    v_3'\\
    d' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
    0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1\\
    v_2\\
    v_3\\
    d\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Second phase:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1''\\
    v_2''\\
    v_3''\\
    d'' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\
    \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1'\\
    v_2'\\
    v_3'\\
    d'\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can easily write a script to use these formulas to calculate your table.

Then you can even multiply your matrices together so your two phases are combined - but I advice agains blindly doing it, as from my computations it shows that \$v_2=v_0\$ will switch between \$0.4\$ and \$0.6\$ at a half-step interval, and combining the matrices would hide that fact.

But a reason to multiply the matrices together would be to find a 'steady-state' soultion (after hiding the one-phase ripple).

$$
\underline{\underline{M}} = \underline{\underline{M_1}}\underline{\underline{M_2}} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

An example `matlab/octave` script using this rule:

```matlab
state = [0,0,0,1]';
mat = [0 0 0 1; 2/9 4/9 0 0; 2/9 4/9 0 0; 0 0 0 1];

for k = 0:3
        state = mat * state
end
```

To find the 'steady-state' solution with the one-phase ripple, all you need to do is to solve the \$\underline{\underline{M}}\underline{s}=\underline{s}\$ equation - so you need to find the eigenvectors of \$\underline{\underline{M}}\$. With `matlab/octave`, it's simply `[vectors, values] = eig(mat)`, that returns

```
vectors =

        0        0   0.8944   0.6565
        0   0.7071  -0.4472   0.2626
   1.0000   0.7071        0   0.2626
        0        0        0   0.6565

values =

Diagonal Matrix

        0        0        0        0
        0   0.4444        0        0
        0        0        0        0
        0        0        0   1.0000
```

You can see that only the second and fourth column is useful, but the second has a 0 for \$d\$, so only the last one will work for us. The corresponding eigenvalue is 1, so the vector satisfies the previous matrix equation, but \$d\neq1\$. No problems tho, as matrix multiplication is linear, so \$\underline{\underline{M}}\underline{s}=\underline{s}\rightarrow\underline{\underline{M}}k\underline{s}=k\underline{s}\$, so we can scale our vector so \$d=1\$: `vectors(:, 4)/vectors(4,4)` results in

```
ans =

   1.0000
   0.4000
   0.4000
   1.0000
```

I have to note that the existence of this solution does **NOT always** guarantee that the system will always converge on this value. For checking if it converges, you can analyze the stability of the system, or just simulate based on your initial state.

For stability, you need to check the eigenvalues of the matrix. We already computed them to be 0, 1 and \$\frac{4}{9}\$. They all lie inside the unit circle, except for the 1 but that's caused by our pseudo-state variable `d` incorporating the input, so the base linear system is stable, and thus, must converge *to some state*. In this case, the input forces it to converge to our state.

Note: In boths steps, the system acts like a linear system. The only reason I diverged from the normal linear system analysis procedure is because of this systems two-step nature, and with this 'fake' state variable I could get rid of it. It made matters a bit more complicated when talking about the stability (as this 'system' acts like it has input), but I think in this case this detour worth it.

## EDIT - on generalizing the analysis of these kinds of circuits

I have been thinking on it for some more time, and I think it's worth seeing how could we generalize all of this.

I took some shortcuts, that might not always be viable, so I'll now elaborate them.

#### Analysis in discrete time

The biggest shortcut I took was considering this circuit in discrete time. This might or might not always work. The circuit already had some simplifications, for example instant transition of the switches, zero resistance of the switches and no parasitics or leakage. With all those aside, I think analysing the circuit in discrete time is a valid choice, but this might not always be the case.

#### Eliminating input dependence

I used the state variable \$d\$ to get rid of input dependence, and thus our system can be described by a single matrix, and computed a bit easier.

Linear systems (in discrete time, siso example) are usually described by the  form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\underline{x}[k+1]\\
y[k]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\underline{\underline{\Phi}}&\underline{\Gamma}\\
\underline{C}^T & D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\underline{x}[k]\\
u[k]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In my previous analysis I got rid of both \$y\$ and \$u\$. I could only do the later because the input is a linear function, but that is not always the case.

#### Combining matrices to skip states & outputs

The combining of the matrices resulted in having a new 'system' (quotes because of the elimination of output & input) that models every other step of the original system, but skips others. The benefit was an easier steady-state solution finding.

### Analyzing without these shortcuts

Some preconditions that we still need

- every 'state' of the circuit is linear
- transitions happen instantly

Other precondition we don't always need:

- input is a linear function (we can solve for arbitrary inputs)
- output is a state variable

First of all, we need to decide what domain to analyze the circuit in.

#### Discrete time

The good news is that we can still come up with a system that models the original. We can do even better than my previous method with shortcuts.

The main idea is still to combine matrices. The problem is that we don't only have a matrice transforming states, but we have inputs and outputs.

Consider a two-step system described by \$\Phi_1; \Gamma_1; C_1; D_1; \Phi_2; \Gamma_2; C_2; D_2\$, making \$x[k]; u[k]; u[k+1]\rightarrow x[k+2]; y[k]; y[k+1]\$. We can easily make a two-input-two-output linear system from them:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x[k+2]\\
y[k]\\
y[k+1]\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi_2 \Phi_1 & \Phi_2 \Gamma_1 & \Gamma_2 \\
C_1 & D_1 & 0\\
C_2 \Phi_1 & C_2 \Gamma_1 & D_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x[k]\\
u[k]\\
u[k+1]\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By using \$x[k+1] = \Phi x[k] + \Gamma u[k]\$. The same approach can work for multiple phases too, and does not need us to incorporate the input function into the system. This also does not 'skip' any outputs.

#### Continuous time

It's a bit harder, especially if the input is not 'nice' in some aspect.

We need to solve all continuous-time systems (one for each state of the switches), and come up with a general solution for any initial state, any input, and possibly, any time (at most any time between entering the phase and leaving it).

We can then start with the initial conditions and phase, use the solution of the current phase and input to calculate the output and also the 'end state', the state the system is at when we (instantly) transition to the next phase. We then can use the solution of the solution of that phase to continue calculating, using the previous end-state as initial state.

This is quite cumbersome to do by hand, and also not as easily automatable as the previous one was. I have one shortcut in mind: if you are not interested in the output in-between the state transition, only the values at them, then you might come up with a list of formulae \$f: (old_state, u(t), start_time, end_time) \rightarrow (next_state, output_at_transition)\$ in closed form, and use them to 'jump' between the states. This needs you to come up with a closed-form formula for calculating state & output based on any time and initial condition, which might not always be possible. I think (but that's only a suspicion) that it *might* be easier to do this using matrix exponents, but I'm not sure at that.

#### Closing notes

Analyzing these 'multi-phased' circuits is not straightforward.

If we consider them in discrete time, then it becomes way easier, as all we need to do is to use a different rule at each timestep, what can be a bit confusing, but we can modify the system a bit to behave more like a normal system and use the same rule again and again.

If we use continuous time, we sadly have to do the analysis differently. We can use the 'end state' of one phase as initial state for the next one, but solving for any input and initial state is not always straightforward.

Finding 'steady-state' is easy with the discrete version (if it exists, that might depend on the input as well). Given the input, we can use for ex. the final value theorem to find it. For continuous system, it's harder, as we can's use anything involving \$t\rightarrow\infty\$ due to the phase changes. We can still try to solve for a state that becomes itself after all the state transitions, but that will be significantly harder, especially if a non periodic (or wrong period) input is present.